# Regarding the Hooke's law and how it can be described using stress and strain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, spring, elasticity

Can someone kindly explain to me the how the relationship marked as (2) below is obtained from the relationship marked as (1).

In our Physics class, our lecture wrote down the following relationship,

According to the Hooke's law,

```
'F' is proportional to 'e' -----------(1)
From this we can write that,
'F/A' is proportional to 'e/l' ----------(2)
Hence we can write,
F/A = E*(e/l) ----------(3)
```

Here, I do not understand how he was able to write the line I have marked as (2) from line I have marked as (1). I mean how can we jump from line marked as (1) to the line marked as (2)?

Is there a more recommended way to obtain the relationship marked as (3) from the relationship marked as (1)?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps recommending migrating the question would be better than voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking on how to go from

$$ F  \propto \delta $$

where $F$ is force and $\delta$ is deflection

to

$$  {F\over A}  \propto  {\delta \over \ell} $$

where $\ell$ is length and $A$ is area.

So understanding that strain $\epsilon = \delta/\ell$ is proportional to $\delta$ the displacement is easy because the denominator $\ell$ is the original length and thus a constant.

The question now is why is stress $\sigma = {F \over  A}$ is proportional to force $F$ needs a small caveat.

In general were are talking about **engineering stress** which is defined as force over *the original area* $A$. This is opposed to **actual stress** which is the force of the instantaneous area $A^\star < A$

So for engineering stress the $A$ is the original area and thus $F /A$ is proportional to $F$.

But for actual stress the $A^\star$ changes with load and thus $F/A^\star$ is **not** proportional to $F$.